# How can I remove NaN values from some columns in a csv file?

Tags: python

I tried to do some basic statistics on a csv file in python.What I'm trying to do is making a dictionary of headers and the values of  special columns.But there are some NaN values which makes the following error on my code

```
import csv
reader=csv.reader(f,delimiter=',')
import numpy as np
header=next(reader)
dataset=[]
  for line in reader:
d=dict(zip(header,line))
for field in ['Reviews','Rating']:
    np.isnan('Rating','Reviews')
    d[field]=int(float(d[field]))
    dataset.append(d)
```

I tried to use numpy.isnan to remove NaN values
but I got this error

```
 return arrays must be of ArrayType
```

Therefore,How can I remove the NaN values?

Answer (score 0):

not sure what your data looks like but I'm guessing the NaN values are strings

you can do

```
d=dict(zip(header,[l for l in line if l != "NaN"]))
```

while you're reading them in to drop the NaNs

but best to post a sample of your data so we can actually see what youre working with

Answer (score 0):

Depends if the `NaN` values are `NaN` or `"NaN"`, you can use:

### NaN not a string:

```
df=df.dropna() #take rows from your dataframe that are finite or not equal to NaN as NaN.
```

### NaN as string "NaN":

```
df[(df != "Nan").all(1)] # take rows from your DataFrame that does not have any "NaN" value from any column
```